# How to ignore instance lable in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

[image]
this is the graph for Dataflow records processed.
I have run two instances of my project on my local system. and my Prometheus server is scraping values from both instances. if I run the same "dataflow" (one of my APIs which generates these metrics). from both the instance then it creates two graphs. because they are coming from two different instances. you can see Dataflow-Product-1 has two graphs. what I want is data from both the instances of the same Dataflow should be combined in one graph. can we do that?

here is the Data
[image]

[image]

in above Screen shot you can see that there are two graphs of Dataflow-Product-1 one is running at 15.. and other on 10 what i want is the same graph which is running on 15 should decline to 10 and other graph should not generate?
what can be the Query ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you pls add an example of query result that you want to have in the end. I understand that you want to group values, but you say that you don't want to aggregate them. I did not fully understood your problem

Answer (score 1):

if you want to combine them I suppose you mean to `sum` or `count` them. Because you said some [aggregate function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators). Then you can use the `without` function to not take into account the specific label you want: `instance` or `dataflowId` or both. Something like this:

```
sum without(instance) (integration_total_record_processed_count)
```

But if you want to show only one line of the graph (not the graph as you said), you can use the label matching inside `{}`.

```
integration_total_record_processed_count{dataflowId="Dataflow-Product-1"}
```

Comment: Combine as in I don't want to add them. as you can see the screenshots Dataflow-Product-1 marks 15 and then again there is another graph for Dataflow-Product-1 marks 10. so if I use Sum it will show 25  which I don't want. for more context the Data which is to say 15 or 10 is the number of records that get process per request.
SO the graph should continue from 15 to 10 and not create a new graph....

Comment: ok, i added one option to not use `sum` or `count`. I am suspicious that it is very simple and it is not what you want. Can you pls add an example of query result that you want to have in the end. I understand that you want to group values, but you say that you don't want to aggregate them. that is contradictory ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

- your Query should look like this to omit  Prod 2, which shows other than Prod 2
  `intergration_total_record_processd_count{dataflowid!="Dataflow-Prodct-2"}`

Answer (score 0):

That is not theoretically possible it seems. I don't want to do any kind of operation on my results. and still, club the result of the same id.
to overcome this situation I used Pushgateway and manipulated the result as per results.